# How is the port address decoded?

Tags: io, x86, logic, port, hardware

According to the image below, it says the output ports are from F0-F7H. My question is how are these ports addresses determine? For example, F0(active low) (Y0) is determine from the inputs A0-A7 inputs? If so, how are these input ports mathematically come to F0?

[image: I/O port decoder]

Comment: I have a feeling that [reading the datasheet](https://www.futurlec.com/Datasheet/74ALS/74ALS138.pdf) will be more useful then asking a hardware question on a programming forum.

Comment: This hardware question will help understand a software assemble language question. I read the truth table and still can't understand how those ports F0-F7h are mathematically derived.

Comment: The datasheet shows you everything you need to know... The logic diagram on page 3 of the datasheet I linked shows how each input will drive each output.

Comment: The IC requires HHL on G1,G2A,G2B to be in an enabled state. From there, the inputs on A0,A1,A2 will drive Y0-Y7 according to the truth table.

Comment: Your specific truth table for this diagram will be slightly different due to the NAND gate on the G2B pin before the IC.

Comment: Thanks Clark for your technical input but I'm still confuse as to how F0 is derived from the inputs because pin 6 (G1) enable to the chip on high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 74ALS138 is a 1-8 demultiplexer, this means it takes a number between 0 and 7 and activates one of its eight output lines (active low).

The A, B and C input signals are the three bit encoding the input number (2<sup>3</sup> = 8) while G1, GA and GB are the enable signals.
To enable the chip G1 must be high and GA and GB must be low, any other combination will disable the chip (all output is high).

To have G1 high we must have the bit 4 of the address high, analogously bit 5, 6 and 7 must be high.
Finally, bit 3 must be low.

This gives an address of the form `1111 0xxx`, ranging from 0f0h to 0f7h.
The lowest three bits select the output line.

Regarding the tie between A, B and C and the outputs, you can start with a truth table:

```
A B C    Y0 Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6 Y7 
0 0 0    0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
0 0 1    1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1
0 1 0    1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   
0 1 1    1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1
1 0 0    1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1
1 0 1    1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
1 1 0    1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
1 1 1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0
```

Each output Y<sub>i</sub> must be computed independently; since each of them is zero exactly once, there is no need to optimize it with a  [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) and since there are a lot of ones, working with [Maxterms](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-8/minterm-maxterm-solution/) is definitively better.

So for example for Y0 the formula is

```
Y0 = A + B + C
```

Due to the rules when dealing with maxterms (It's a product of sum, each factor being negated iif the input variable is 1).
The other relations are

```
Y1 = A  + B  + C'
Y2 = A  + B' + C
Y3 = A  + B' + C'
Y4 = A' + B  + C
Y5 = A' + B  + C'
Y6 = A' + B' + C
Y7 = A' + B' + C'
```

This doesn't take into account the enable inputs, internally we can have a single enable signal E by taking E = G1 * GA' * GB' then the truth table for Y0 becomes

```
E A B C    Y0
0 0 0 0    1
0 0 0 1    1
0 0 1 0    1 
0 0 1 1    1
0 1 0 0    1
0 1 0 1    1
0 1 1 0    1
0 1 1 1    1
1 0 0 0    0
1 0 0 1    1
1 0 1 0    1
1 0 1 1    1
1 1 0 0    1
1 1 0 1    1
1 1 1 0    1
1 1 1 1    1
```

This just translates to `Y0 = E' + A + B + C`.

If you consider that `X + Y === (X' * Y')'` by [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and call `(X * Y)'` [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) you see that `Y0 = NAND(E, A', B', C')` which is exactly the implementation in the [74ALS138 datasheet](https://www.futurlec.com/Datasheet/74ALS/74ALS138.pdf):

[image: 74ALS138 implementation with NAND logic]

*[Datasheet courtesy of Matt Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986696/how-is-the-port-address-decoded#comment82942274_47986696)*

Answer (score 1):

The table in the data sheet seems quite clear: Y0 is active if A0, A1, A2, and A3 are low and A4, A5, A6, and A7 are high. Y1 is active under all the same conditions except A0 is high.

Comment: I understand the truth table. What I don't understand is how F0 derived from the truth table?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Thanks for the comments to help me connect the dots in figuring out how the address is map to the input address]

Thanks for the comments to help me connect the dots in figuring out how the address is map to the input address